# Identical multivariate polynomial definition

Tags: polynomials

Where can I find a formal definition of two multivariate identical polynomials?

In univariate polynomials, two are identical if the coefficients of the similar powered variables are equal. In multivariate polynomials I suppose that the monomials, which are composed of multiple variables, should be completely identical in powers, coefficients, and everything across the compared polynomials.

Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are right. Essentially the same definition as in the one indeterminate case.

Comment: Analogously to the single variate case, you set the terms of same variable and power equal to each other, determining that the coefficients are the same.

Comment: Thank you both!  @AndréNicolas what's that indeterminate case?

Comment: "Indeterminate" is a fancy word for what one informally calls "variable."

Comment: Ok thanks. Very fancy indeed.